# What regular expression can I use to match a cell reference?

Tags: regex, c#-3.0

For one of my projects I want to use a regular expression to match a string like "REF:Sheet1!$C$6".

So far I have done

```
public static private bool IsCellReference()
        {

           string CELL_REFERENCE_PATTERN = @"REF:Sheet[1-9]!$[A-Z]$[0-9]";

            Regex r = new Regex(CELL_REFERENCE_PATTERN);
            Match m = r.Match("REF:Sheet1!$C$6");
                if (m.Success) return true;
                else return false;
        }
```

but it is not working.  It is returning false.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You'll probably have to escape a number of those characters. `!` and `$` are often reserved in regular expressions. I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer because I'm not instantly sure, it's just a(n intelligent) guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape your $ signs.

`REF:Sheet[1-9]!\$[A-Z]\$[0-9]`

See [Regular Expression Language Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) for more information

Also, this page is good for testing your regexes: [A better .NET Regular Expression Tester](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)